# Getting error '#1111 - Invalid use of group function'

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am getting this error with following query. Please help me correct it.

`#1111 - Invalid use of group function`

- `t_person` table contains person details
- `tr_category` table contains category details
- `tr_testimonial` table contains rating value details

All tables have `personpkid` as common field.

```
SELECT
    p.*,c.*,t.*
FROM
    t_person p
    LEFT JOIN tr_category c ON p.personpkid=c.personpkid
    LEFT JOIN tr_testimonial t ON p.personpkid=t.personpkid
WHERE
    avg(t.ratingvalue)>=5
GROUP BY
    p.personpkid ORDER BY approvedate DESC
```

Thank you in advance,
SG

Comment: @shevski if i could down vote you I would. What's the point of putting that and not giving him a link or description that may help him achieve what you suggested.

Comment: @RyanMurphy sure, http://www.catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3):

When you're using a grouping expression to filter results, you need to use `HAVING` clause.  Try this:

```
SELECT
    p.*,c.*,t.*
FROM
    t_person p
    LEFT JOIN tr_category c ON p.personpkid=c.personpkid
    LEFT JOIN tr_testimonial t ON p.personpkid=t.personpkid
GROUP BY
    p.personpkid ORDER BY approvedate DESC
HAVING
    avg(t.ratingvalue)>=5
```

Comment: Thank you very much Aleks G. This works. It was just issue of sequence of lines.Thanks again.